# How to create a variable from existing variables so that the new variable is a cumulative summation of a variable (var1) while var1[1] == var2[1]

Tags: r

I would like to have a new data by creating additional variables from the existing ones with a single function. I posted my data result from excel below."WT" is a new variable to be created by a summation of "W" & "W1". "Estimated" is another variable to be created by using the first value of the "Actual"
`(Actual[1]=Estimated[1])` while `for i in 2:nrow(data), Estimated[i] is Estimated[i-1] + Change[i].`

```
Day Actual  Change  Estimated   W   W1  WT
1   186.55  -24.20  186.5512051 150.9816575 108.5068806 259.4885381
2   165.83  -14.08  162.3463561 161.0925    63.11266186 224.2051619
3   155.42  -8.19   148.2676871 161.2860254 36.70926735 197.9952927
4   135.75  -4.76   140.0788766 183.3773607 21.35182179 204.7291825
5   132.27  -2.77   135.3158826 183.5233478 12.41921528 195.942563
6   128.50  -1.61   132.5455032 185.8537875 7.223594767 193.0773822
7   127.60  -0.94   130.9341213 189.6309519 4.201579583 193.8325315
8   123.12  -0.55   129.9968664 196.6067281 2.443834622 199.0505627
9   122.43  -0.32   129.4517153 200.9331242 1.421448183 202.3545724
10  123.49  -0.18   129.13463   202.8374037 0.826780551 203.6641843
11  126.17  -0.11   128.9501984 201.6633084 0.480894125 202.1442025
12  128.97  1.76    128.8429244 204.0241743 0   204.0241743
13  130.95  1.79    130.6037286 207.2370343 0   207.2370343
14  130.34  1.78    132.3922679 206.4310664 0   206.4310664
15  139.78  1.74    134.1738539 201.5581715 0   201.5581715
16  139.05  1.77    135.9133858 204.5833776 0   204.5833776
17  137.07  1.79    137.6790267 207.1880918 0   207.1880918
```

I tried the following though it was not successful:

```
Try <- function(ag,data) {
  data <- read_excel...
  ag = 1.20
  New <- data
  for (i in 1:nrow(New)) {
  New$WTT <- ag*(New$W + New$W1)
  New$Est[i] <- (New$Actual[1]*New$Day[i]<2)+ (New$Est[i-1] + New$Change[i-1])*(New$Day[i]>1)

  return(New)}
 }
newdata <- Try(ag=1.20, data = data)
```

then I found Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialized column: 'Est'. The 'Est' variable was not also created

Comment: What have you tried already? Match column indices and row indices and reassign? However, what is the expected result? Is it updating already existing columns or you have some other data before this?

Comment: the data I posted includes those values calculated in excel and are to be calculated using R. This is because this task is among a large simulation work to be undertaken

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that the equation for estimated is `Estimated[i] = Estimated[i-1] + Change[i-1]` is that right?

Comment: Thank you. You are right it is Estimated[i-1] + Change[i-1].